# A problem where I have tried to use binomial theorem but getting a wrong answer which is $x^5$/42 please help me

Tags: binomial-theorem

If constant term in the expansion of ($x^3$ +
$\frac{k}{x^8})^{11}$.
  Is 1320. Find k.
As to my work I found the middle term as it will be a constant one but answer is coming absurd

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You will get a better response to your question if you show your work and where you are stuck. I realize you are getting the wrong answer, but we'd like to see your work so we can help.

Comment: Sir I have written my efforts

Answer (score 0):

The constant term will come from the value of $n$, $0 \leq n \leq 11$, such that $$3n = 8(11-n).$$ That is, $n = 8$. The binomial coefficient for the term $$(x^{3})^8 \cdot \left(\frac{k}{x^8}\right)^{3} = k^3$$ is $$\frac{11!}{8!3!} = 165.$$ Given that the constant term equals $1320$, we have $165k^3 = 1320$, that is, $k^3 = 8$. Hence, $k=2$.